# Match values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

Consider the following two data frames:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(vals = c("a","b","c"), index = 1:3)
> 
> df1
  vals index
1    a     1
2    b     2
3    c     3
> 
> df2 <- data.frame(a = c("x1","x2","x3"), b = c("a,b,c","b,c","a,c"))
> 
> df2
   a     b
1 x1 a,b,c
2 x2   b,c
3 x3   a,c
```

I am trying to replace the values of `b` in data frame `df2` by values `index` from data frame `df1` using column `vals` as a matching criteria. However, column `b` of data frame `df2` is a comma separated string which makes it more complicated.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2$c <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df2$b),","),function(x) {
                 paste(df1[na.omit(match(x,df1$vals)),"index"],collapse=",")
                })

#    a     b     c
# 1 x1 a,b,c 1,2,3
# 2 x2   b,c   2,3
# 3 x3   a,c   1,3
```